# Definition for Chiral Spin Liquid

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, chirality, spin-models

What is the definition of [chiral spin liquid](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chiral+spin+liquid%22)?
Especially what does chiral mean here?
I encounter a lot of terminologies with [chiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_%28physics%29). It seems they mean differently in different contexts. If you could generally answer what chiral means, it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

A 2D chiral spin liquid (CSL) is a spin liquid state that breaks time-reversal and parity symmetries. For a CSL system with open boundaries, there may be chiral edge states propagate in only one direction, which is analogous to the case of integer quantum Hall effect.

Generally speaking, I think *chiral*, in a sense, means *a particular direction*, which is usually associated with *broken time-reversal symmetry*.

Answer (score 1):

X.G. Wen first introduced the idea of chiral spin state (not necessarily spin liquid) in his [paper](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevB.39.11413). As Kai has mentioned above, the state breaks time reversal symmetry.

It's partially characterized, for example on a triangular lattice, by

$E_{123} = <S_1\cdot(S_2\times S_3)>$

If the system has T, then $E_{123}=0$ since spin operator $S$ is odd under T. Thus, a nonzero $E_{123}$ suggests a CSL.

A recent technical and detailed classification based on PSG on CSL is [here](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.094437).